# Why did LH412 fly in circles, far from its destination?

Tags: flight-path, online-tracking

On 5 June 2022 Lufthansa flight 412 from Munich to Newark flew 3 clockwise circles over the sea just west of Brittany:

[image: Flight Aware screenshot]

<sup>([FlightAware.com](https://de.flightaware.com/live/flight/DLH412/history/20220605/1410Z/EDDM/KEWR))</sup>

Why did it fly these circles? It was many hours away from the US and ended up diverting to St. John's (YYT).

Comment: Assuming you are referring to yesterday's (June 5 2022) LH-412 flight (Lufthansa) it ended up being diverted to YYT en-route. No reasons have been published, yet, that I can locate. Could be any number of reasons, from unruly passenger(s) who calmed down enough to continue, to some sort of non-critical hardware issue. Also, it wasn't "flying in circles far from its destination" as much as it was doing so, while still within divert distance to an airport in Europe. i.e. it hadn't yet gotten to a point-of-no-return over the ocean.

Comment: My first thought was holding prior to oceanic entry to increase separation with preceding aircraft, which is [sometimes causing issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRdp7AXTzO8). However, I cannot see any other aircraft entering oceanic airspace on [FR24's playback feature](https://www.flightradar24.com/2022-06-05/17:22/12x/DLH412/2c20ba91) in front of them.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @CGCampbell

Comment: @FreeMan not at all, I don't yet know _why_ the circular pattern was done, which was the question asked. At the time I posted my comment, we didn't yet know for sure what flight was actually being asked about.

Comment: Gotcha, @CGCampbell. All I could see was time stamps of "x hours ago" and lost the fine details...

Answer (score -2):

There was a special needs passenger on board who was terrified and was having physical meltdowns. The crew tried to keep him calm but he became too agitated.

Comment: Do you have firsthand knowledge of this flight? If so you should say so; if not you should add supporting references.